# QBPOSFC throws file not found exception

Tags: vb.net

I currently want to connect my vb. Net application to quickbooks pos v9. When I declare my session manager like this. Dim sessionManager As New QBPOSsessionManager. I get an error that says file does not exist. Please help

Comment: What's the full class name for QBPOSsessionManager? Do you have references to the assembly that defines it in your projects and the namespace Imports for the class name?

Comment: Or when you say "file does not exist" do you mean at runtime? So you're compiling this OK but when you run the program it can't find your QuickBooks file?

Comment: I've added QBPOSFC as my reference but it's weird that I cannot see the reference folder under solution explorer. I added my inports statement as Imports QBPOSFC3Lib

Comment: Yes on runtime it throws an exception that says FileNotFoundException

Comment: OK, so you'll either need to work out how to pass a filename to this object, or work out which file it's currently trying to read and why that's wrong. I don't know this API to help sorry. If you can't debug into the class to see what the missing file is, you could try using sysinternals procmon but it generates a lot of logs you'll have to filter down to the find the line you want.

Comment: What do I have to Google?